How to disable Jenkins JaCoCo plugin publisher
I have multiple test stages in my Jenkins pipeline that require jacoco:prepare-agent goal of JaCoCo maven plugin to run, but the actual report and coverage results (for plot) need to be generated only once. This goal also seems to trigger publisher in jenkins JaCoCo plugin that I have installed in my Jenkins.
The problem is that if publisher is triggered more than once, the plot and column record is being duplicated. As jacoco:prepare-agent goal is needed in every test stage, there are a lot of identical plots on my dashboard.
I have looked for insights in plugin Jenkins documentation and plugin site but didn't find anything related.
In the pipeline code I have tried
jacocoPublisher(disabled: true)

but it took no effect on plugin behavior.
Is there a way to disable jacocoPublisher automatic triggering for certain stages in Jenkins pipeline?

Please add your Jenkinsfile to the question.
